# in PHP using 'if statement' to find a word

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a text file with several lines of text, eg:

```
JOHN
MIKE
BEN
JAMES
PETE
```

I read that contents into an array, with each line of text, placed into a seperate element of the array.

I then tested each element of the array, to find a phrase, say 'BEN'

ie:

```
for( $a = 0; $a < 5; $a++ )
{
if ($contents[$a] == "BEN") 
{
echo "$contents[$a]";
}
}
```

but this fails to recognise 'BEN'

but if I was looking for a number instead of a word, from:

```
JOHN
MIKE
10
JAMES
PETE
```

or from...

```
5
10
15
20
25
```

and used the same code, to look for the number, eg: say '10'

```
if ($contents[$a] == 10)
    {
    echo "$contents[$a]";
    }
```

then this works ok, so why ?

Also...

I dont get the problem if the individual lines of text, are already in the array, only when they are READ from the text file...

```
$contents[0] = "JOHN";
$contents[1] = "MIKE";
$contents[2] = "BEN";
$contents[3] = "JAME";
$contents[4] = "PETE";
```

Comment: How are you reading the text file into the array?  Can you add the source code for this part.

Comment: I think the problem most likely lies in how your are reading the text file into the array. Can you post the code for how you are doing that?

Comment: What is the output of print_r($contents);

Answer (score 4):

I presume that the strings you read from the text file contain the trailing end-of-line character for each line, that's why you cannot find `BEN` (since that string does not include the trailing end-of-line character). Use the `trim` function to get rid of trailing whitespace in your strings before comparing them against strings.

Comment: Thanks Tamas,I'll try that later.

Comment: Tamas: So why dosnt the same problem occure when its a number ?

Comment: @mac due to type conversion. For example, `10=="10\n"` return `true`, but `"10"=="10\n"` return `false`

Comment: mac: Because when it's a number, it converts the string, so it discards the trailing end-of-line character.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
if ($index = array_search('BEN', $contents) {
    echo $contents[$index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because when you read line from file, you also have newline (`\n`) character at the end of string. Use [`rtrim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to strip it.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) for comparing strings in PHP.